# Excel VBA constant as argument

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, constants

Sorry in advance, I'm a self-taught VBA programmer, and I'm not sure how to phrase my question! 
I've declared constants which have similar names, i.e.

```
Public Const BP1Enable = "something1something:someotherthing1someotherthing"
public const BP2Enable = "something2something:someotherthing2someotherthing"
```

etc.

I have 10 of these constants.  I have a sub with these constants as arguments:

```
Sub FieldEnable (ByVal enableconst)
```

Now I want to call the FieldEnable sub in a loop using i as counter:

```
For i = 1 To 10

 BPfieldname = "BP" & i & "Enable"
 FieldEnable enableconst:=BPfieldname
Next i
```

This does not work, what is happening is that the "value" assigned to enableconst in the sub FieldEnable, is "BP1Enable" instead of the value of the constant BP1Enable namely "something1something:someotherthing1someotherthing".

How can I use the variable BPfieldname when calling the sub FieldEnable?

I hope this makes sense.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your variables into a single Array.

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

**EDIT:** as @sina has correctly pointed out, VBA does not allow constant arrays,

so instead of trying this

```
Dim BPEnable = {
  "something1something:someotherthing1someotherthing",
  "something2something:someotherthing2someotherthing",
  ....
}
```

you should try this

```
Dim BPEnable
BPEnable = Array( _
  "something1something:someotherthing1someotherthing", _
 "something2something:someotherthing2someotherthing", _
 "..."
)


For i = 0 To UBound(BPEnable)
 BPfieldname = BPEnable(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The best guess would be to use a constant array, but constant arrays are not supported by VBA.

Therefore you could go with building an array out of your constants before you start your loop:

```
Dim BPEnable
BPEnable = Array(BP1Enable, BP2Enable)
For i = 0 To UBound(BPEnable)
 FieldEnable enableconst:=BPEnable(i)
Next i
```

Another option would be to declare all constants as one long string with some defined separator and use a split function on that string to generate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are going to be using this "constant" in more than one place, more than one function, you can *effectively* make an array constant, that can even be called that way.

```
Public Sub Test()
    For i = LBound(BPEnable) To UBound(BPEnable)
        Debug.Print BPEnable(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function BPEnable() As Variant
    BPEnable = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Pi", "Four")
End Function
```

Immediate Window:

```
One
Two
Three
Pi
Four
```