# Declaration of a block of public const variables in VBA

Tags: vba

I would like to declare a large number of public constant variables in VBA. Is it necessary that I must prepend each and every variable with public const?

i.e.

```
Public Const varA as Integer = 1
Public Const varB as Integer = 3
Public Const varC as Integer = 9
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you tell us more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515611/excel-vba-constant-as-argument) You can use arrays

Comment: If they're all integers, I'd use an enum

Comment: @mehow I have more than 200 variables (of different data types) that I need to declare, but all of just constants.

Comment: if they have to be public const then the answer is yes, you do.

Answer (score 0):

No, actually you do not need to include `Public Const` before each value, you only need it before the first value if it is formatted like this:

```
Public Const varA As Integer = 1, _
            varB As Integer = 3, _
            varC As Integer = 9
```